# Running FFMPEG in electron using react, either doesn't load without any error or throws an SharedArrayBuffer is not defined when run after building

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, ffmpeg, electron, ffmpeg-wasm

I am trying to build a web based media conversion tool to be able to ship with electron.

```
  const ffmpegInit = async () => {
    try {
      const baseURL = "https://unpkg.com/@ffmpeg/core-mt@0.12.6/dist/esm";
      const ffmpeg = ffmpegRef.current;
      ffmpeg.on("log", ({ message }) => {
        console.log(message);
      });
      // toBlobURL is used to bypass CORS issue, urls with the same
      // domain can be used directly.
      await ffmpeg.load({
        coreURL: await toBlobURL(
          `${baseURL}/ffmpeg-core.js`,
          "text/javascript",
        ),
        wasmURL: await toBlobURL(
          `${baseURL}/ffmpeg-core.wasm`,
          "application/wasm",
        ),
        workerURL: await toBlobURL(
          `${baseURL}/ffmpeg-core.worker.js`,
          "text/javascript",
        ),
      });
      setLoaded(true);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("------->>>", err);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    ffmpegInit();
  }, [ffmpegRef]);
```

This piece of code is directly taken from [FFMpeg's usage guide](https://ffmpegwasm.netlify.app/docs/getting-started/usage#transcode-webm-to-mp4-video)

On viewing the network's tab of my electron's dev tool, I see a `11.4 MB` file being downloaded with resource size of around `32 MB`. Which seems fair.

But the code never moves ahead of the `await ffmpeg.load()` call without throwing any error.

I then proceeded to build the react app using vite and then only I could see the app throw an error:

> ReferenceError: SharedArrayBuffer is not defined

After digging through some GitHub issues on the same I found out that `SharedArrayBuffer` has something to do with `cross-origin-isolation` for security reasons so I updated my `vite.config.ts` file to the following:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import crossOriginIsolation from "vite-plugin-cross-origin-isolation";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), crossOriginIsolation()],
  optimizeDeps: {
    exclude: ["@ffmpeg/ffmpeg", "@ffmpeg/util"],
  },
  server: {
    headers: {
      "Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy": "same-origin",
      "Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy": "require-corp",
    },
  },
});
```

as u can see I also added `vite-plugin-cross-origin-isolation` but still ffmpeg refuses to work.

I saw this [tutorial in YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lHcnhSgKgyM) and he made it work with ease, even after following the same steps I am unable to get it to working.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You need ffmpeg to exclusively run in the renderer process? Otherwise, you can use ffmpeg-static for the binaries and run it in main process